# Joomla install with custom sample data — Customize text during install

Tags: module, cms, articles, installation

What would be the best way for me to customize custom sample data during installation of Joomla? In my particular case, I would like to replace certain words (or tokens, like %NAME%, %CITY%, etc.) within articles and the stored content of various types of modules (Custom HTML, Widgetkit 1.x).

If not during installation, then would having something that would be replaced on-the-fly (i.e. {myreplacecomponent name}, {myreplacecomponent city}) be more viable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little while after asking the question, I used NoNumber's [ReReplacer](https://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer) for the dynamic replacements.